# Guzzle sendAsync return response

Tags: php, guzzle

I want to return response from method sendAsync by Guzzle, but it return empty.

```
public function getliveflight_guzzle()
{
        $url = 'https://www.tesflight.com/ajax/pingFlightSearch?d=CGK&a=DPS&date=2018-08-18&adult=1&child=0&infant=0&service_class=&airlines=["MALAYSIAAIR"]&subsidy=true&page_view=roundseperate&refund_deposit=&refund_currency=';
        $client = new Client(['headers' => ['Accept' => 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01', 'Accept-Language' => 'en-us,en;q=0.5', 'X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest']]);

        // Send an asynchronous request.
        $request = new Psr7\Request('GET', $url, [
            'curl' => [
                CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17',
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => '0',
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => '0',
                CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => TRUE,
                CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true,
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => '1',
                CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true
            ]
        ]);
        $promise = $client->sendAsync($request)->then(function ($response) {
            return $response->getBody()->getContents();
        });
        $promise->wait();
}

public function actionTesguzzle()
{               
        $response = $this->getliveflight_guzzle();
        $response = json_decode($response, TRUE);
        print_r($response);
}
```

Also i want try to save $response->getBody()->getContents() into variable then i try to echo it outside the sendAsync method, but it display empty. But if i echo it inside sendAsync it will show the data. How can that happen?

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return value from function `return $promise->wait();`, try this:

```
public function getliveflight_guzzle()
{
        $url = 'https://www.tesflight.com/ajax/pingFlightSearch?d=CGK&a=DPS&date=2018-08-18&adult=1&child=0&infant=0&service_class=&airlines=["MALAYSIAAIR"]&subsidy=true&page_view=roundseperate&refund_deposit=&refund_currency=';
        $client = new Client(['headers' => ['Accept' => 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01', 'Accept-Language' => 'en-us,en;q=0.5', 'X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest']]);

        // Send an asynchronous request.
        $request = new Psr7\Request('GET', $url, [
            'curl' => [
                CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17',
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => '0',
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => '0',
                CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => TRUE,
                CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true,
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => '1',
                CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true
            ]
        ]);
        $promise = $client->sendAsync($request)->then(function ($response) {
            return $response->getBody()->getContents();
        });

        return $promise->wait();
}

public function actionTesguzzle()
{               
        $response = $this->getliveflight_guzzle();
        $response = json_decode($response, TRUE);
        print_r($response);
        echo json_last_error_msg();
}
```

you can also use function [json_last_error_msg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) to debugging decode of json

Answer (score -1):

```
public function index()
{
    $client  = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['verify' =>false]); //ssl verifyication 
    $request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    $promise = $client->sendAsync($request)->then(function ($response) {
        $sd=$response->getBody()->getContents();
        $datas=json_decode($sd);
        return response()->json($datas);
        // return view('show',compact('datas'));
    });
    return $promise->wait();
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.